# Как вернуться назад на две страницы, без кнопки и через 5 секунд?

Tags: php

Форма регистрации вызывается не на всех страницах, поэтому возникла необходимость возвращаться именно на ту, откуда пришли... Но не на одну, а на две страницы, так как при обработке формы выводится сообщение, типа "вы успешно зарегистрированы" на 2-ой уже странице... Как правильно вернуться на две (несколько) страниц, не прописывая конкретный адрес?

Comment: Для таких целей передаётся в качестве дополнительного параметра адрес, откуда пришли. И после успешной регистрации/логина производится редирект на указанный адрес.

Answer (score 3):

можно через javascript

```
  function back(){
    document.history.go(-2);
    }
setTimeOut('back()',5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

В форме регистрации сделайте +1 поле

```
<input type="hidden" name="backurl" value="<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']?>" />
```

в сообщении:

```
...
?><p>Вы успешно зарегистрировались!</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function(){ top.location.href='<? echo (!empty($_POST['backurl'])) ? $_POST['backurl'] : '/'; ?>'; }, 5000);
</script>
<?
...
```

Answer (score 0):

На несколько, скорее всего, никак, так можно использовать

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`
+
[СУПЕРГЛОБАЛЬНЫЙ МАССИВ $_SERVER](http://www.softtime.ru/info/articlephp.php?id_article=69)

Не забудьте, рефер надо проверять, и кроме всего прочего - нужно его сохранить, сессия, куки - как больше нравиться.

UPD:

Чтобы вернуться...

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="секунды;URL="адрес">
```

Comment: А если пользователь не вызовет "регистрацию", то как, к примеру, нужно установить Куки, чтобы при уходе со страницы они закончились?..

Comment: Убивать куки/сессию, если не было перехода на страницу)

Comment: Вот я и не пойму, как проверить переход, если при переходе будет уже другая страница, на которой этот куки/сессия нужны?.. А не нужны они, если со страницы ушли дальше, без регистрации... То есть, где-то, перед окончанием скрипта данной страницы их нужно сразу выключать?..

Comment: Вопрос был как реализовать, а не напишите мне код как это делается) Сессию можно обновлять до тех пор, пока юзер не уйдет на нужную страницу, правда громоздко... Проще на каждой конкретной странице объявлять сессию со значением адреса страницы. У меня просто регистрация попроще построена, и возврат идет просто на индекс. Если делать как вы хотите, если тело инклюдится в `index.php` в шапке индекса объявлять сессию, если  адрес не равен к примеру `index.php?i=register`. Ну, я думаю идею донёс.

Comment: и вернёт этот код человека на 1 страницу назад а никак не на 2) но в принципе тоже ничего))) про сессию вспомнить никогда не поздно))) или куку...